# Reading In A String and comparing it C

Tags: c, string

Im trying to create a C based string menu where a user inputs a command and then a block of code runs.

Whatever i do the conditional is never true:

```
char *input= "";
fgets(input, 50, stdin);
printf("%s",input);
printf("%d",strcmp( input,"arrive\0"));
if(strcmp( input,"arrive\0")==0){....
```

Im fairly new to c and am finding strings really annoying.

What am i doing wrong?

Note: current code crashes my program :(

Comment: Please consider using strncmp() over strcmp(), it will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Why does strcmp() cause headaches?

Comment: @TimPost strcmp() works perfectly fine, it does exactly what it's supposed to - compare 2 strings, which seems appropriate in this case. strncmp() ofcourse works perfectly fine too, but it doesn't lessen headaches, and it's neither better or a substitute for strcmp()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why strcmp always return non 0:**

`strcmp` will return 0 only when the strings are identical.  As for why it's evaluating to different always.  It is because fgets puts a newline character at the end of your input buffer before the null termination.

```
/*Will print 0 if you type in arrive<enter>*/
printf("%d",strcmp( input,"arrive\n"));
```

---

**Why your program crashes:**

Another problem is that `input` should be a char buffer.  Like so: `char input[1024];`
Currently you have `input` as a pointer to a null terminated string (which is read only memory)

---

**Friendly suggestion:**

Also don't put the null terminated `\0` inside the string literals.  It is implied automatically when you use a string literal.  It doesn't matter to double null terminate as far as `strcmp` is concerned, but it may cause problems elsewhere in your future programs.  And people will wonder why you're doing double null termination.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
#define BUFF_LEN 256

char input[BUFF_LEN];

fgets(input, BUFF_LEN, stdin);
```

What you have , `*input` is a pointer to an address of memory that has not been allocated, hence can not be used by your program. The result of using it as you are is undefined, but usually leads to a `segmentation fault`. If you want to access it as a pointer, you will first need to allocate it:

```
char *input = malloc(BUFF_LEN);
```

... of course, test that for failure (NULL) then free() it after you are done using it.

Edit:

At least according to the [single UNIX specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), fgets() is guaranteed to null terminate the buffer. Its not necessary to initialize input[].

As others have said, it is not necessary to include null / newlines when using strcmp().

I also strongly, strongly advise you to get used to using `strncmp()` now, while beginning to avoid many problems down the road.

Comment: the count fgets takes in includes the null character, so there is no need for the `- 1`.

Comment: What specific problems down the road do you suspect might happen? See [What's wrong with strcmp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353504/whats-wrong-with-strcmp)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the first line with

```
char input[50];
memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
```

Edit:
However, the real problem why strcmp doesn't return 0 is you have to "trim" the string read from fgets, which in most cases, includes a newline character.

Comment: Or just `char input[50] = {0}` instead of wasting cycles `memset()`-ing everything.

Comment: Why the memset for a buffer that will be overwritten by `fgets` anyway?

Comment: It's just a convention to prevent C learners from getting caught with common pitfalls.

Comment: @shinkou - I initially suggested it too, however fgets() is guaranteed to null terminate the buffer. Minor nits, however.