# What's wrong with strcmp?

Tags: c, string, deprecated, strcmp

In the responses to the question *[Reading In A String and comparing it C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576398/reading-in-a-string-and-comparing-it-c)*, more than one person discouraged the use of `strcmp()`, saying things like

> I also strongly, strongly advise you to get used to using strncmp()
>   now, ... to avoid many problems down the road.

or (in [Why does my string comparison fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069925/using-if-statement-to-compare-strings/4070043#4070043) )

> Make certain you use strncmp and not strcmp. strcmp is profoundly
>   unsafe.

What problems are they alluding to?

The reason [`scanf()` with string specifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/scanf#Security) and [`gets()` are strongly discouraged](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/gets) is because they almost inevitably lead to buffer overflow vulnerabilities. However, it's not possible to overflow a buffer with `strcmp()`, right?

> "A buffer overflow, or buffer overrun, is an anomaly where a program, while writing data to a buffer, overruns the buffer's boundary and overwrites adjacent memory."

( -- [Wikipedia: buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/buffer_overflow)).

Since the strcmp() function never writes to any buffer, the strcmp() function cannot cause a buffer overflow, right?

What is the reason people discourage the use of `strcmp()`, and recommend `strncmp()` instead?

Comment: Why don't you ask those people?

Comment: *Trust me*. `strncmp()` is no better (or worse) than `strcmp()`.

Comment: The comments on the linked SO article are mostly junk

Comment: Using `strncmp` to protect against strings which are not null terminated just papers over the root problem which is that you have a non-terminated string. It will just mess up on the next function that assumes it's null-terminated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While `strncmp` can prevent you from overrunning a buffer, its primary purpose isn't for *safety*. Rather, it exists for the case where one wants to compare only the first N characters of a (<s>properly</s> possibly NUL-terminated) string.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html):

> The `strcmp()` function compares the two strings `s1` and `s2`.  It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than `s2`.
>
> The `strncmp()` function is similar, except it compares the only first (at most) `n` bytes of `s1` and `s2`.

Note that `strncmp` in this case cannot be replaced with a simple `memcmp`, because you still need to take advantage of its stop-on-NUL behavior, in case one of the strings is shorter than `n`.

If `strcmp` causes a buffer overrun, then one of two things is true:

1. Your data isn't expected to be NUL-terminated, and you should be using `memcmp` instead.
2. Your data *is* expected to be NUL-terminated, but you've already screwed up when you populated the buffer, by somehow not NUL-terminating it.

---

Note that *reading* past the end of a buffer is still considered a **buffer overrun**.  While it may *seem* harmless, it can be just as dangerous as *writing* past the end.

Reading, writing, executing... it doesn't matter. Any memory reference to an unintended address is undefined behavior. In the most apparent scenario, you attempt to access a page that isn't mapped into your process's address space, causing a page fault, and subsequent SIGSEGV. In the worst case, you sometimes run into a \0 byte, but other times you run into some other buffer, causing inconstant program behavior.

Comment: I don't see how strcmp() can cause a buffer overrun, even if both those things are true. Could you say a few more words about what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Imagine you have `char buf[100]` in which every character is `'a'` (it is not NUL-terminated). If you pass this buffer to `strcmp` (assuming the other parameter is a longer string, then `strcmp` will continue comparing at `buf[100]` and so on, overrunning the buffer.

Comment: I can see how *writing* past the end of a buffer causes problems. But strcmp() doesn't do that, right? Would you mind adding a few words to your answer about what exactly goes wrong if strcmp() goes on *reading* past the end of a buffer?

Comment: Reading, writing, executing... it doesn't matter. Any memory reference to an unintended address is undefined behavior. In the most apparent scenario, you attempt to access a page that isn't mapped into your process's address space, causing a page fault, and subsequent SIGSEGV. In the worst case, you sometimes run into a `\0` byte, but othertimes you run into some other buffer, causing inconstant program behavior.

Comment: Good point. Please hit the above "edit" button and add it to your answer. I've done a lot of programming on machines that never page fault, so that particular "page fault" problem never happens on those machines, but this is exactly the sort of thing I want to know about so my C is portable to machines where this sort of thing can and does happen.

Comment: If you want to ensure portability, you should ensure correctness. No matter what the machine, reading past the end of a buffer will invoke undefined behavior. The CPU may happily read zeros, or the memory controller might catch fire.

Comment: "it exists for the case where one wants to compare only the first N characters of a (properly NUL-terminated) string." is _not_ correct.  From the C spec "The strncmp function returns an integer ... accordingly as the possibly null-terminated array pointed to by s1".  Neither `s1` nor `s2` of `int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);` need to be C strings.  Independently, they can simply be strings or they can be arrays of `char` without being "properly NUL-terminated".

Comment: @chux Hmm, it seems I will have to re-visit my answer. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 8):

A string is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".

The only case where `strncmp()` would be safer than `strcmp()` is when you're comparing two character arrays as strings, you're certain that both arrays are at least `n` bytes long (the 3rd argument passed to `strncmp()`), and you're *not* certain that both arrays contain strings (i.e., contain a `'\0'` null character terminator).

In most cases, your code (*if it's correct*) will guarantee that any arrays that are supposed to contain null-terminated strings actually do contain null-terminated strings.

That added `n` in `strncmp()` is not a magic wand that makes unsafe code safe. It doesn't guard against null pointers, uninitialized pointers, uninitialized arrays, an incorrect value of `n`, or just passing incorrect data. You can shoot yourself in the foot with either function.

And if you're trying to call `strcmp` or `strncmp` with an array that you *thought* contained a null-terminated string but actually doesn't, then your code already has a bug. Using `strncmp()` might help you avoid the immediate symptom of that bug, but it won't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares two strings character to character until a difference has been detected or  the `\0` is found at one of them.

On the other hand, `strncmp` provides a way to limit the number of characters to be compared so if the strings do not end with `\0` the function won't continue checking after the size limit has been reached.

Imagine what would happen if you are comparing two strings at this two memory regions:

`0x40, 0x41, 0x42,...`
`0x40, 0x41, 0x42,...`

And you are only interested in the two first characters. Somehow `\0` has been removed from the end of the strings and the third byte happens to coincide at the two regions. `strncmp` would avoid comparing this third byte if `num` parameter is 2.

**EDIT**
As the comments below indicate, this situation is derived from a wrong or very concrete use of the language.

Comment: If you want to compare memory regions, use `memcmp`. In C, a "string" is a null-terminated character sequence. If you have strings, use `strcmp`. If you don't, don't.

Comment: Sure, `strcmp` would then make the comparison "safe", but that's really just deferring the problem.  Your non-null-terminated string would then cause undefined behaviour later on in your program.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I do agree, just wanted to pinpoint a case where `strncmp` is safer to use than `strcmp`

Comment: As I understand it, `strncmp` doesn't exist for "safety", but rather "I want to compare the first N characters of these strings".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You should make that an answer.

Comment: Things that don't end in `\0` are not strings