# pallindrome program not working please check attached the code and the output

Tags: c, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

i have tried to make a program to check the pallindrome manually on paper it should work
but it doesnt.
i have attached the output with the code

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <string.h>      
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
 char str[100];
 int i,l,k;

 printf("type the desired to string to check pallindrome\n");
 gets(str);
 l=strlen(str);
 printf("%d\n", l);

 k=l-1;
 char temp[100];

 for(i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
   temp[k]=str[i];
   --k;

 }

 if(strcmp(temp, str)==0)
 {
   printf("pallindrome\n");
 }
 else
 {
   printf("not a pallindrome\n");
 }


}
```

here is the output

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dERFQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWcAp.png)

Comment: You have not null-terminated `temp`.  Alternatively, use `strncmp`

Comment: 1. `void main()` should be `int main()` 2. `gets` -buffer overruns. use `fgets`

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the NUL terminator at the end of `temp` right after the `for` loop:

```
 for(i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
   temp[k]=str[i];
   --k;

 }
 temp[i] = '\0';
```

Otherwise, the `strcmp` function will cause [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: what is a null terminator? and why would strcmp cause a ub without it? I am fairly new to programming so i dont know much.........

Comment: @DevZer0 `NUL` terminator in C, is the `\0` character appended after a C-string: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string . `strcmp` will not know how far to read in characters if it is missing and might tread into memory you don't own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353504/whats-wrong-with-strcmp

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The array `temp` does not contain a string because you forgot to append it with the terminating zero character '\0'.

So the call of the `strcmp`

```
if(strcmp(temp, str)==0)
```

results in undefined behavior.

Also the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the function `fgets`.

Also to check whether a string is a palindrome there is no need to declare an auxiliary array.

The code can look like

```
printf("type the desired to string to check pallindrome\n");
fgets(str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

str[strcspn( str, "\n" )] = '\0'; // to remove the new line character '\n'

size_t n = strlen( str );
printf( "%zu\n", n );

size_t i = 0;

while ( i < n / 2 && str[i] == str[n-i-1] ) ++i;

if( i == n / 2 )
{
    printf("pallindrome\n");
}
else
{
    printf("not a pallindrome\n");
}
```

You could write a separate function that checks whether a string is a palindrome.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n-i-1] ) ++i;
    
    return i == n / 2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char s[N];
    
    printf( "Type a desired string to check whether it is a palindrome: " );
    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );
    
    s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    
    if ( is_palindrome( s ) )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome.\n", s );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" is not a palindrome.\n", s );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Type a desired string to check whether it is a palindrome: abcdedcba
"abcdedcba" is a palindrome
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if( i == n / 2 )` be `if( i >= n / 2 )` - Consider strings of an odd length